# Parse JSON to model in React Native getting undefined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to map my JSON Object to a model class like that:

```
export class Product {
constructor(props) {
    this.name = props.Name
    this.items = props.Items
    this.price = props.Price
    this.productID = props.ProductID 
    this.medias = props.Medias
  }
}
```

But when I get JSON and try to parse to my Model I'm getting the following error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'mostSoldProductsApiResponse.map'

There's my parse code:

```
const mostSoldProductsApiResponse = await mostSoldProductsApiCall.json().Products;
const arrayProducts = mostSoldProductsApiResponse.map(function(item) {
return new Product(item.Product)
            })
```

If I don't parse the JSON Object to `new Product()` constructor, the code works fine. But I would like to organize the code. Therefore I would like to implement Product class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be you are using `await` not on what you expect.

The line `await mostSoldProductsApiCall.json().Products` is actually first returning a promise, then `await`ing on the resulting promise field `Products` which is undefined because it is not the result of the promise.

something equivalent to:

```
const promise = mostSoldProductsApiCall.json()    // this is the promise
const unresolvedProducts = promise.Products       // this is undefined
const mostSoldProductsApiResponse = await unresolvedProducts  // this resolves to undefined
```

### Solution

Use parenthesis to `await` on the actual promise, like so:

```
const mostSoldProductsApiResponse = (await mostSoldProductsApiCall.json()).Products
```

Another option:

```
const mostSoldProductsApiResponse = await mostSoldProductsApiCall.json()
const arrayProducts = mostSoldProductsApiResponse.Products.map(function(item) {
  return new Product(item.Product)
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed to `const mostSoldProductsApiResponse = await mostSoldProductsApiCall.json();
              const arrayProducts = mostSoldProductsApiResponse.map(function(item) {
                return new Product(item.Product)
              })`

but  I'm getting `[TypeError: mostSoldProductsApiResponse.map is not a function. (In 'mostSoldProductsApiResponse.map(function (item) {
                  return new _Product.default(item.Product);
                })', 'mostSoldProductsApiResponse.map' is undefined)]
  line: 113796,
  column: 64,`

Comment: You missed “Products”. Look closer at the second option. Try: mostSoldProductsApiResponse.Products.map

Comment: Thanks! it changed the code to pass json to Product constructor after async request and it worked :D

Comment: I really missed Products.... thanks a lot. My code now looks like: 
 `const mostSoldProductsApiCall = await fetch(GET_MOST_SOLD_PRODUCTS_URL_WEB_API, dataRequest);
              const mostSoldProductsApiResponse = await mostSoldProductsApiCall.json(); 
              const arrayProducts = mostSoldProductsApiResponse.Products.map(function(item) { 
                return new Product(item) 
              })`